# Passing Jquery Autocomplete Selected Item ID to C# Json

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller

Here's my partial code for an Autocomplete function in jQuery:

```js
$("#mpvalue").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            datatype: 'json',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetEmpDetails")',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { term: $("#detail").val() },
            success: function (data) 
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $(".list").append ( ui.item.name + ui.item.age)
```

C#:

```cs
public ActionResult Search(string name) {
    name = Request.QueryString["term"];
    return Json(routeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

If the user selects an item which outputs the values `ui.item.name` and `ui.item.age`, how do I pass these values over to controller in MVC?

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't seem to be complete. You have to elaborate more.

With the current understanding of your question-
source option in autocomplete is the source of data to the control. If you want to pass a value to the controller after selection of an item you have to give a ajax call and pass the selected item($("#mpvalue").val() here would give selected value).